# Animating chain driven vehicle with rigid bodies

Tags: modeling

I want to simulate a chain driven vehicle, which responds to the ground or obstacles by the usage of rigid bodies.
I've tried to create one chain part and let it follow a bezier curve or even tried to follow this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftiFE9gnTyc 
What ever I do, although setting the chain part to active, the whole chain doesnt respond to the ground. Only the wheels respond, which are driving the chain.
Does anybody has a hint for me or has even modeled something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it finally by hand:
Create one chain link. Calculate length of chain link by rigid number of elements around one wheel, e.g. 180° + 6 elements = rotate each element by 30°. Length = sin(30)*wheel_radius. Build it for both wheels, only for the outer half-circle.  Connect the open ends with chain-links between. Set all active (rigid body). Connect them with constraints. Use hinges (beware of direction -> hinge uses z-axis).
[image][image]

It is an easy way, but a little bit annoying for big chains.